# Typescript, don't lose type information using generics

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

In the code below the `getValue` method on the `DataBankService` class is losing type information (see example). Is it possible keeping the type information?

https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-rx-playground-gqnzuq?file=index.ts

```
import { Subject } from "rxjs/";

export interface DataObject<T> {
    value: T;
    observable: Subject<T>;
}

export class DataBankService {
    private dataBank: DataBankProperties;

    constructor() {
        this.dataBank = new DataBankProperties();
    }

    public getValue<T extends keyof DataBankProperties, V>(property: T) {
        return this.dataBank[property].value;
    }
}

 class DataBankProperties {

    money: DataObject<number> = this.createDataObject();
    token: DataObject<string> = this.createDataObject();
    testament: DataObject<object> = this.createDataObject();
 

    private createDataObject<T>() {
        return {
            value: null,
            observable: new Subject<T>(),
        };
    }
}

const dataBank = new DataBankService();

// token is now type >> token: string | number | object
const token = dataBank.getValue('token');
// I would like this to be type string

// token is now type >> token: string | number | object
const money = dataBank.getValue('money');
// I would like this to be type number
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with an assertion on the return type - using your generic as the key for DataBankProperties. I've renamed it K for convention (as in K for key)

```
public getValue<K extends keyof DataBankProperties>(property: K): DataBankProperties[K]['value'] {
   return this.dataBank[property].value;
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Now the type is DataObject<number>/DataObject<string> instead of number/string

Comment: You casted it as a dataObject not a primitive

Comment: Thank you so much you seem pretty good at TS. Do you have any suggestions on good TS resources?

Comment: Just pick a topic and start working away at it! To learn how this particular pattern works - I found this TS documentation really useful - if you can get your head around how the Pick example works, that's pretty much what's being done here: 
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#index-types

Comment: Once you're comfortable with that, the next level would probably be conditional types  - it took me a long time to understand how to use these, but one of the good examples is here. https://artsy.github.io/blog/2018/11/21/conditional-types-in-typescript/ . Lastly I did a  presentation on advanced TS a couple years back - some stuff here could be useful to you as a sort of road map (ignore the react context stuff, the first half of the presentation has some examples) https://github.com/m-b-davis/typescript-hocs-context/blob/master/Presentation.pdf

Comment: Again, thanks a lot, I hope to improve my TS the coming years ;)

Comment: No worries. Good luck on your journey!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest creating a type for inferring the generic type of DataObject:

```
type DataObjectTypeInference<T> = T extends DataObject<infer U> ? U : never;
```

And then use it like that:

```
public getValue<K extends keyof DataBankProperties>(property: K) {
    return this.dataBank[property].value as DataObjectTypeInference<
        DataBankProperties[T]
    >;
}
```

First, you define a type which looks after the generic type of DataObject of the current type instance. I personally prefer not to couple between property names and like the comment before me. I like it to be inferred by TypeScript, so if you decide to change value key to another name, it won't affect the type inference.

After that, you make a type assertion of the variable to be DataBankProperties[T] which gives you the type of DataObject and now you use the type we built and infer the generic type of DataObject.